# How can I set a reference variables to a specific item, in *ngFor?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this code

`<ng-container *ngFor="let item of results;let i = index">
        <ion-item #triggerElement  lines="none">`

I need to set the reference #triggerElement  to the item with the index 3. How can I do this? I tried with a div

`<div *ngIf="i == 2" #triggerElement ></div>` but it throws me an error: " Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined". Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of handling this logic (which is very fragile) in the template, try using `@ViewChildren`.

Get hold of all the elements of the array in the template into `QueryList` in your TS class and find the element at required index -

Your template -

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of results;let i = index">
    <div #triggerElement lines="none">
    {{ i }}   {{ item }}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Your component -

```
import { Component, VERSION, AfterViewInit, ViewChildren, TemplateRef, QueryList, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChildren('triggerElement') elements: QueryList<ElementRef>;      <---------

  results = [ 'Cheese', 'Tomato', 'Olives', 'Basil'];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const element = this.elements.find((e, index) => index === 3);    <-----------
    console.log(element);
  }

}
```

I have recreated at this link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/vm-tooltip-directive?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: take careful, index goes from 0, so index==3 is the fourth element

Comment: That was been asked. Please refer question, it says - ''I need to set the reference #triggerElement to the item with the  **index 3**. How can I do this? I tried with a div''

Comment: It was only a comment, I don't like the name of the variable "thirdElement", but sure you're free to choose it

Comment: Thanks, that was my bad. Updated!

Answer (score -1):

It seems like it is a special item, so I think it is worth to separate it from the rest. A simple solution then could be,

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of results | slice:0:2"> .. </ion-item>
<ion-item #triggerElement lines="none"> .. </ion-item>
<ion-item  *ngFor="let item of results | slice:3"> .. </ion-item>
```